# How to check if parent-child association exists in Firebase using angularfire2

Tags: angularfire2

I have this json data structure in Firebase below. I need to create a new child item but I want to check if it exists first. So basically I need check `~/parentKey11/childKey21` exists before pushing a new item (in the array of items).

```
  "nodeA": [
    {
      "parentKey11":  {
        "childKey21": {
          "items": [
            {
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
            }
          ]
        },
        "childKey22": {
          "items": [
            {
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
            }]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Just for simplicity. I can check the parent key first. But code below does not seem to work:

```
const parentRef = this.af.database.object(`/nodeA/parentKey11`, { preserveSnapshot: true });

parentRef.subscribe(data => {
    if(data == null) {
        console.log('data does not exists')
    } else {
        console.log('data exists');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
const parentRef = this.af.database.object(`/nodeA/parentKey11`, { preserveSnapshot: true });

parentRef.subscribe(data => {
    if(data.val()==null) {
        console.log('data does not exists')
    } else {
        console.log('data exists');
    }
});



const parentChildRef = this.af.database.object(`/nodeA/parentKey11/childKey21`, { preserveSnapshot: true });

parentChildRef.subscribe(data => {
    if(data.val()==null) {
        console.log('data does not exists')
    } else {
        console.log('data exists');
    }
});
```